# Hola estoy usando FPDF para generar un reporte y tengo el siguiente inconveniente

Tags: pdf, fpdf, formato

Estoy realizando un reporte pdf en fpdf en laravel 8, el inconveniente que se me presenta es que no logro dar un formato segun las imagenes de referencia, mi codigo actual esta de la siguiente manera

```
  public function datosPDF()
        {
            $dato = "JOTA JOTA JOTA JOTA";
            $lugar = "DIRECCION: LOS ALISOS S/N - JOSE GRANDE - AAHH EL SOL DEL NORTE";
            $codigo = "9856321";
            $tipoControl = "CONTROL CIUDADANO";
            $contenido = "Un atardecer dorado ilumina el horizonte, pintando el cielo con tonos cálidos y suaves. La brisa acaricia la piel mientras las olas rompen con su murmullo tranquilizador en una playa de arena fina. Un lugar perfecto para relajarse y conectar con la naturaleza, donde el tiempo se desliza suavemente, invitando a la reflexión y al descanso.";
            $fechaHora = "2022-07-28 08:44:30";
    
            $pdf = new Fpdf();
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->Image('images/pdf/Group9.png', 0, 0, 210);
            $pdf->SetXY(65, 14);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 18);
            $pdf->Image('images/pdf/escudo.png', 15, 3, 20);
            $pdf->Image('images/logo5.png', 170, 4, 25);
    
            $pdf->SetXY(10, 56);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);
            $pdf->SetFillColor(0, 0, 0);
            $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 255, 255);
            $pdf->Cell(35, 10, utf8_decode('DATOS'), 1, 0, 'C', true);
            $pdf->Cell(30, 10, utf8_decode('LUGAR'), 1, 0, 'C', true);
            $pdf->Cell(30, 10, utf8_decode('CODIGO.'), 1, 0, 'C', true);
            $pdf->Cell(30, 10, utf8_decode('TIPO CONTROL'), 1, 0, 'C', true);
            $pdf->Cell(40, 10, utf8_decode('CONTENIDO'), 1, 0, 'C', true);
            $pdf->Cell(30, 10, utf8_decode('FECHA Y HORA'), 1, 1, 'C', true);
    
            $pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
            $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 7);
    
            $pdf->Cell(35, 10, $dato, 1);
            $pdf->Cell(30, 10, $lugar, 1);
            $pdf->Cell(30, 10, $codigo, 1);
            $pdf->Cell(30, 10, $tipoControl, 1);
    
            $pdf->MultiCell(40, 5, $contenido, 1);
            $pdf->Cell(30, 10, $fechaHora, 1);
    
            $pdf->Output(('Reporte.pdf'), 'I');
            exit();
        }
```

De esta manera se encuentra el codigo del fpdf para reporte en pdf pero haciendo uso de las MultiCellpara darle un formato mejor no esta funcionando y esta de esta manera
[image: Este es el problema que se presenta]

PERO ESTOY INTENTANDO QUE TENGA ESTA FORMATO

[image: el resultado que estoy tratando de realizar es el siguiente]

Comment: Lo que necesitas es usar el script 'Table with Multicells' (http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php) para obtener el resultado que deseas